# User/Subscriber sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a table that shows all the registered users to which the current user has not yet subscribed to. But once he has subscribed someone, I need to filter that list to exclude those.

Let's say the theres a table called **subscribed** which lists the User and to whom he is subscribed to.

```
|UserId||SubscriberID|
```

Its easy to make it into multiple queries, but I've been unsuccessfully trying to make it into one query, to save an extra loop of MySQL calls.

Here's What I have so far:

```
 SELECT u.UserID, FullName, UserName from users u 
    LEFT JOIN subscribed t ON 
     ((u.UserName LIKE '%$search%' OR 
       u.Email LIKE '%$search%') AND 
      ({$_SESSION['ID']} = t.UserID 
        AND t.FollowerID != u.UserID)
     )
```

I know the last part of the query is wrong, since I only compare if the UserID and the FollowerID don't match for one particular row, not the entire table.

Comment: The last part needs to be in the Where clause of the query, so it will work within each row, rather than joining on the whole table...

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a list of results in table A that are not in table B, you have two options. Either use the `NOT IN` syntax, or `LEFT JOIN` and look where the PK field in the B table is `NULL`.

`NOT IN` example:

`SELECT a.id FROM a WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id FROM b)`

`LEFT JOIN` example:

`SELECT a.id
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id)
WHERE (b.id IS NULL)`

Comment: I should mention that using `NOT IN` with a subquery is going to require MySQL 5.0 or greater, and will be slower than the `LEFT JOIN` idea. I personally prefer the semantics of the `NOT IN` syntax despite it's lack of performance as long as it doesn't significantly affect your application's response times.

Comment: MySQL 4.1 supports subqueries too.

Comment: Oh thanks Bill, that sounds familiar now that you mention it.